# How to develop design criteria for subsystems in addition to the systems?

Tags: project-management

Context: 18yr fresh out of high school and have started my undergraduate engineering course at my University.

For my first ever group project, we are asked to develop a fire extinguisher vehicle. The vehicle has 4 subsystems, or 4 parts that we need to focus on. The driving, structural, water delivery part and the controlling the vehicle part.

I am tasked to develop design options for the water delivery part. It obviously needs to have a water reservoir (container), tubing, pump and some nozzle. Then, I have to a develop design criteria for these components.

The problem is that I am struggling to develop specific criteria. For example, I can come up with sustainability, safety, maintainability, economic feasibility and on and on. We all know that a pump should have all those characteristics just like any other components in other subsystems (driving etc). But how can I be specific to MY WATER DELIVERY SUBSYSTEM? I can't say water efficacy is a design criteria since this is not a criteria for tubing, pump or nozzle.

Comment: I would start with some research about how current fire trucks are set up. How much water do they have on board? How far can they throw the water and how much per minute? How much power is available for the pump? From there, you can deduct specific requirements that your vehicle should meet to keep up with the state of the art, for example carry 2000 l of water and throw it 30 m far.

Comment: I think you shall setup the goal of your water delivery system, understand the demand on its performance, then determine the criteria to ensure the system performs as designed to meet the end goal.